# Gradle compatible Maven repository or alternative for local usage

Tags: maven, gradle, android-studio, shared-libraries, local

The situation:

We have several apps, which use a library developed by ourselves. All app projects as well as the library are under constant development.

Our goal is to have a local maven repository, which allows us to always build the apps with the latest library version, like all those dependencies listet in the Android-Studio dependency chooser here

[image]

We don´t want to use the central maven repository, as it makes our code public.

Is there any chance to have a lokal maven repository which is going to be fully compatible with Android Studio and Gradle or is there any other (easy) alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a local Maven repository manager, which will let you maintain a set of private artifacts for your organization. There's some documentation here: http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html but the brief explanation is that you can set up a repository that's similar to Maven Central except it's private. There are various repository manager software packages, including Apache Archiva, Artifactory, and Sonatype Nexus.

Comment: Thank you. I´ve tried to get them working and it´s quite hard I think. Nexus seems to be the light-weightest of all...Isn´t it possible to solve the dependency download by a simple php script?